Integral concerning the floor function
I have a problem with the following integral:
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\{x\}\right)^{[x]}}{[x]}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\{x\}\right)\,dx
$$
where $[x]$ is the floor function and $\{x\}:=x-[x]$. I tried to solve it using the following idea.
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\{x\}\right)^{[x]}}{[x]}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\{x\}\right)\,dx &=
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(x-[x])\right)^{[x]}}{[x]}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(x-[x])\right)\,dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(x-k)\right)^{k}}{k}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(x-k)\right)\,dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)^{k}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\,dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^k\,\cos(x)\,dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{\sin(x)^{k+1}}{k+1}\right|_{0}^{\pi/2}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\,(k+1)}=\frac{2}{\pi}.
\end{align}
Now, I looked it up on Desmos and it tells me that this is wrong. In fact, as you can see in the image, the integral and my result are different.

Did I do something wrong? Thanks for any help.

Your answer seems right. Desmos is just giving an approximation, and how it does so it not clear, so I can't explain the difference.

from scipy.integrate import quad; quad(lambda x: np.sin(np.pi/2*(x-np.floor(x)))**np.floor(x)/np.floor(x) * np.cos(np.pi/2*(x-np.floor(x))), 1, np.inf, limit=5000)
gives about 0.63813 and a convergence warning. I don't think these numerical algorithms are too fond of the infinitely many jumps, probaby would benefit from choosing support points manually. Anyway, $2/\pi$ is within the estimated error.

Making the integration interval $[1,9999999]$ makes Desmos approximate the integral as $0.631485692671$ which is a pretty good approximation for $2/\pi$. Sometimes Desmos has a terrible time approximating integrals with trig functions over large intervals like $[1,\infty)$.

@Noctis. Mathematica does not produce any warning but the results are bad

Let $$f(x)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\{x\}\right)^{[x]}}{[x]}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\{x\}\right)$$ and use Mathematica with the following syntax
R[p_]:=NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> p]
There is no problem or warning. Nice but the result depends very much on the value of the working precision
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & R(p) \\
 10 & 0.6317221476 \\
 20 & 0.6300419923 \\
 30 & 0.6319526217 \\
 40 & 0.6321773132 \\
 50 & 0.6327733152 \\
 60 & 0.6319059416 \\
 70 & 0.6320912143 \\
 80 & 0.6317180264 \\
 90 & 0.6318379131 \\
 100 & 0.6329749100 \\
 200 & 0.6326666679 \\
 300 & 0.6322638105 \\
 400 & 0.6321032001 \\
 500 & 0.6321174712 \\
 600 & 0.6322364980 \\
 700 & 0.6322364980 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Even when the result stabilizes, we are still far away from $\frac 2 \pi$

At least quad manages to get $1/L$ convergence (as one would expect) after providing guiding in form of manual support points at $1,2,3,\dots$, and the limit does indeed appear to be $\frac{2}{\pi}$.
Still, a direct numerical evaluation does not appear to be too favorable. Probably one should first transform the integral in some way.

Code to reproduce the figure:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Lv = np.unique(np.geomspace(1e1, 1e4, 20, dtype=int))
points = np.arange(1,Lv[-1]+1)
f = lambda x: np.sin(np.pi/2*(x-np.floor(x)))**np.floor(x)/np.floor(x) * np.cos(np.pi/2*(x-np.floor(x)))
y = np.array([quad(f, 1, L, limit=1<<16)[0] for L in Lv])
y2 = np.array([quad(f, 1, L, limit=1<<16, points=points[:L])[0] for L in Lv])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(Lv, np.abs(y - 2/np.pi), label="naive quad", ls='', marker='o')
ax.plot(Lv, np.abs(y2 - 2/np.pi), label="quad with manual support", ls='', marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel(r"$L$")
ax.set_ylabel(r"$|I - \frac{2}{\pi}|$")
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.legend()
```

